# What is the error-correcting capacity (randomly errors, or burst errors) of polar code?

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, coding-theory

[Polar codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_code_(coding_theory)), invented by [Arikan](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3917.pdf), with low encoding and decoding complexity. But the minimum distance of polar codes is not great. The normalized minimum distance goes to $0$ with the block size. Yet, the existing decoding algorithms for polar codes can asymptotically achieve channel capacity.

Generally, a code with minimum distance $d$ can correct $\frac{d-1}{2}$ errors (random errors). And Polar code is also error-correcting code, I was wondering how many errors can it correct( e.g. A $[2048, 614]$ with $BEC(0.19)$ polar code.)? Much appreciated.

Comment: To ask for "how many errors can a code correct", if by that we assume (as usual) the maximal amount of errors that the code can guarantee to correct - then the answer is simply  $(d−1)/2$, so your question is equivalent to ask about the minimum distance of that code. Someone might answer that.Notice however that this is not the ultimate measure of how good a code is. What matters is the global probability of decoding error. Modern codes (as Polar codes) intend to dispell that "obsession with distance". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843604/minimum-distance-for-large-codes

Comment: @leonbloy, thanks for the reply.Yes, the polar code does not depend on the distance. BTW, how can I compute the probability of decoding error (e.g. Successive cancellation decoder)? Thx.